# Direct3dX exception and lags with meshes using Directx

Tags: c#, exception, directx

I have a problem with my directX meshes. When I draw more than 4-5 meshes (i use spheres) the Direct3dX exception appears in line where I initialize the mesh. And also I have crazy lags in that case. I use C#.

Thats my drawing function for sphere:

> ```
>     public void draw(Device device)
>     {
>         device.Transform.World =Matrix.Translation(v3CurMeshPos);            
>         device.Material = m;
>         device.RenderState.Ambient = color;
>         mesh = Mesh.Sphere(device, radius, 100, 100); // problem line
>         mesh.DrawSubset(0);
>     }
> ```

Thats my initialization and drawing with directX:

```
    private void devicePanel1_OnCreateDevice(object sender, DirectxGraph.DeviceEventArgs e)
    {
        device = e.Device;
        device.Transform.Projection = Matrix.PerspectiveFovLH((float)Math.PI / 4, devicePanel1.Width / devicePanel1.Height, 1f, 1000f);

        device.RenderState.Lighting = true;
        device.RenderState.CullMode = Cull.None;
        device.Lights[0].Type = LightType.Directional;
        device.Lights[0].Position = new Vector3(10, 10, 0);
        device.Lights[0].Direction = new Vector3(1, -3, -1);
        device.Lights[0].Enabled = true;
    }

    private void updateCamera()
    {
        v3CamPos = new Vector3(0, 0, Util.distance);
        v3CamLookAt = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        device.Transform.View = Matrix.RotationYawPitchRoll(Util.rotX, Util.rotY, Util.rotZ) * Matrix.LookAtLH(v3CamPos, v3CamLookAt, new Vector3(0, 1, 0));

    }

    private void devicePanel1_OnRender(object sender, DirectxGraph.DeviceEventArgs e)
    {
        Draw(device);
    }

    private void Draw(Device device)
    {
        if (rotate_forward)
        {
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                Util.rotX += 0.005f;
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                Util.rotY += 0.005f;
            }
            else if (radioButton3.Checked)
            {
                Util.rotZ += 0.005f;
            }
        }
        else if (rotate_backward)
        {
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                Util.rotX -= 0.005f;
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                Util.rotY -= 0.005f;
            }
            else if (radioButton3.Checked)
            {
                Util.rotZ -= 0.005f;
            }
        }
        updateCamera();
        if (!graph.isEmpty())
        {
            foreach (Node node in graph.nodes)
            {
                node.shape.draw(device);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
mesh = Mesh.Sphere(device, radius, 100, 100); // problem line
```

creates a new mesh in every frame. This is, of course, a big waste of memory that probably leads to the exception.

Instead you should create the mesh once before your application starts and reuse it. You can transform it with world matrices as you need. So you don't have to create a sphere for each radius you need.